# codeigniter + require letters and numbers in password

Tags: validation, codeigniter, passwords, codeigniter-2

I'd like to use form validation to require a password that has BOTH alpha and numeric characters. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric');
```

The issue is that "alpha_numeric" requires that the password only contain letters or numbers, it doesn't require both. Going for the stronger password option here.

Comment: Try using a callback: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a callback for another field, so it's an option.

Comment: Using callback and some regular expressions https://stackoverflow.com/a/65401563/7186739

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could set up a [callback](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) in your controller:

```
public function password_check($str)
{
   if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $str) && preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $str)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

Then, update your rule to use it:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|callback_password_check');
```

Answer (score 15):

An alternate solution that can be easily reused in other projects and localizes your validation rules is to extend the Form_validation class.

In application/libraries/ create a file called MY_Form_validation.php where 'MY' is your subclass prefix set in application/config/config.php.

The class would look something like:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    /**
     * Verify that a string contains a specified number of
     * uppercase, lowercase, and numbers.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param String $str
     * @param String $format
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function password_check($str, $format)
    {
        $ret = TRUE;

        list($uppercase, $lowercase, $number) = explode(',', $format);

        $str_uc = $this->count_uppercase($str);
        $str_lc = $this->count_lowercase($str);
        $str_num = $this->count_numbers($str);

        if ($str_uc < $uppercase) // lacking uppercase characters
        {
            $ret = FALSE;
            $this->set_message('password_check', 'Password must contain at least ' . $uppercase . ' uppercase characters.');
        }
        elseif ($str_lc < $lowercase) // lacking lowercase characters
        {
            $ret = FALSE;
            $this->set_message('password_check', 'Password must contain at least ' . $lowercase . ' lowercase characters.');
        }
        elseif ($str_num < $number) //  lacking numbers
        {
            $ret = FALSE;
            $this->set_message('password_check', 'Password must contain at least ' . $number . ' numbers characters.');
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * count the number of times an expression appears in a string
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param String $str
     * @param String $exp
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function count_occurrences($str, $exp)
    {
        $match = array();
        preg_match_all($exp, $str, $match);

        return count($match[0]);
    }

    /**
     * count the number of lowercase characters in a string
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param String $str
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function count_lowercase($str)
    {
        return $this->count_occurrences($str, '/[a-z]/');
    }

    /**
     * count the number of uppercase characters in a string
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param String $str
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function count_uppercase($str)
    {
        return $this->count_occurrences($str, '/[A-Z]/');
    }

    /**
     * count the number of numbers characters in a string
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param String $str
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function count_numbers($str)
    {
        return $this->count_occurrences($str, '/[0-9]/');
    }
}
```

Then set the rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|password_check[1,1,1]');
```

The rule can be used in many different ways. 'password_check[1,1,1]' would require a password contain a lowercase, uppercase, and number character. 'password_check[5,0,1]' would  require 5 uppercase characters and a number in the password.

The advantages of doing it this way are:

1. All your rules are contained within an easily portable class
2. Sub-validation functions such as 'count_occurences' can easily be used in other validation functions.
3. The class can be modified to use language files in application/language/

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer; I'm upvoting it (since I already accepted another answer). Hopefully it will help future googlers.

Comment: I just loved this function: Anyway I think you have to change        list($username, $lowercase, $number) = explode(',', $format);      to list($uppercase, $lowercase, $number) = explode(',', $format);

Comment: this is really help full answer , I will add it into my blog .

Comment: HI sir, I would like to ask how can I allow special character?

Comment: @Angel You would need to add a function that counts special characters, to update the `password_check` method so it uses that new function to check the string for enough special chars, and to modify the rule. If you get stuck open a new question.

Answer (score -2):

Using CI 2.2.0, there are parameters you can add, like the 'alpha_numeric' parameter, note the piped (cascaded) parameters:

```
function check_password(){
 $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'New Password', 'required|max_length[15]|min_length[6]|alpha_numeric');
 $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('passconf', 'Re-enter', 'required|matches[password]');

 if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE){
  doStuff();
 } else {
  doOtherStuff();
 }
}
```

Look for the Rule Reference near the bottom of [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) page.

Comment: Yes, I read it, but my brain parsed it wrong - my bad... Apologies.