# Codeigniter Form Validation Setting Strong Password Validation Rule In an Array

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am using codeigniter form validation to validate user data when creating new user. I want to add some sort of password criteria for example password must have 
at least one capital letter, a number, and one of !, @, #, $ etc) and there have to be 6-25 characters.

This is the array that I am using for validation rules:

```
$config = array(
           array(
                 'field'   => 'title',
                 'label'   => 'Title',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required'
              ),
            array(
                 'field'   => 'firstname',
                 'label'   => 'First Name',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'lastname',
                 'label'   => 'Last Name',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'phone',
                 'label'   => 'Telephone',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|intiger|min_length[11]|max_length[11]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'email',
                 'label'   => 'Email',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[ci_user.email]|matches[conf_email]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'conf_email',
                 'label'   => 'Confirm Email',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'password',
                 'label'   => 'Password',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[25]|matches[conf_password]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'conf_password',
                 'label'   => 'Confirm Password',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
              ));
```

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve what I need. Thank you

Comment: perform a callback. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525944/codeigniter-require-letters-and-numbers-in-password

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525944/codeigniter-require-letters-and-numbers-in-password) and [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477906/password-must-be-8-characters-including-1-uppercase-letter-1-special-character)]

Comment: Hi, I used the link and added ''trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[25]|matches[conf_password]|callback_password_check|xss_clean'' to my password rule and also created password_check method but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can setup call back function to check password strong validation. and call this function `callback_is_password_strong` in this line of your code.

```
array(
    'field'   => 'password',
    'label'   => 'Password',
    'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[25]|matches[conf_password]|xss_clean|callback_is_password_strong'
),
```

and if you look this function will return true or false and password array rule key is validated only when it returns true

```
public function is_password_strong($password)
{
   if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $password) && preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $password)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Hi I have already tried that but for some reason it doesn't do anything. So it is like the code within callback just gets ignored or the callback function just doesn't get called at all.

Comment: I have added this to my controller and have not created a new library that extends Codeigniter Form Validation. Do I need to do this?

Comment: [Custom validation Rules](https://arjunphp.com/custom-validation-rules-codeigniter/)

Comment: [How to use custom form validation in codeigniter](http://tutsnare.com/custom-form-validation-in-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `callback` function

```
public function check_strong_password($str)
    {
       if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $str) && preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $str)) {
         return TRUE;
       }
       $this->form_validation->set_message('check_strong_password', 'The password field must be contains at least one letter and one digit.');
       return FALSE;
    }
```

Usage

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('adminPassword', 'password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[25]|callback_check_strong_password');
```